# Hex Value Multiplication Overflow

Tags: java, android

I am trying to multiply 2 Hex values together and receive a Hex value as an output.  I currently take a string that contains hex values, convert it to an integer to multiply, then convert it back to a hex string.

This is an example of multiplying in decimal (base 10).

```
//this works for all cases
//operand1, operand2 & displayValue are strings that should be any value from 0-F
long solutionInt = 0;
int currentBase = 10;
solutionInt = Integer.parseInt(operand1, currentBase) * Integer.parseInt(operand2, currentBase);
displayValue = Integer.toString(Integer.valueOf(Long.toString(solutionInt)).intValue());
```

This is where I am having trouble, multiplying in hex (base 16)

```
//this does NOT work for larger numbers (that would overflow)
//operand1, operand2 & displayValue are strings that should be and value from 0-F               
long solutionInt = 0;
int currentBase = 16;           
solutionInt = Integer.parseInt(operand1, currentBase) * Integer.parseInt(operand2, currentBase);
displayValue = Integer.toHexString(Integer.valueOf(Long.toString(solutionInt)).intValue());
```

When multiplying by larger hex values that would cause an overflow (ie: 0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFF), my android app crashes and I receive the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

I need `displayValue` to hold a hex string that (if converted to a number) would be of size int.  I am not sure if there is some sort of overflow causing this error, or something else with an activity in android.

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(Long.toString(solutionInt)).intValue()` is equivalent to `solutionInt`. Why all the longhand?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use BigDecimal.  it is possible to construct a big decimal from a hex string and then use the multiple method.

see http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t126470-no-hexadecimal-parsing-formatting-for-biginteger.html